# Gmaps issue: Huge icons rendering KML files

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Today every sites that I've rendering kml files appear with huge icons for points. I'm using customized icons.

The icon's resolution is 32x32 and the icon drawn by gmaps has a size bigger than 300x300

This sites has been working fine for years and I've changed nothing.

http://mirador.dipusevilla.es/

http://tripcaddy.es/mapa

Is that a google maps issue that is comming up today?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me like the `<scale>` element within `<IconStyle>` has been switched on. Your PNG files are quite small, but you are specifying a scale of `30` in some cases (the KML is quite dense and not easy to parse).

While in the past that would probably have been ignored, it is in the [specification](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#iconstyle) that the image is scaled by the factor specified in `<scale>`. Had it been `1` you probably wouldn't have noticed.

Comment: You're right! I had the scale tag empty on every sites. I've set it to <scale>1.1</scale> an it's working now. Do you know why <scale>1</scale> doesn't draw icons?

Comment: @alasarr It's a `float` so you could try `1.0`. The docs show "1" on its own, though.

Comment: I've already test with 1.0 but doesn't work I've to set it to 1.1 so the icons become distorted. any ideas?