# Google Maps stops showing up placemark icons

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm experimenting a very strange behaviour with kml placemark icons.

Yesterday that was happening [Gmaps issue: Huge icons rendering KML files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11115696/gmaps-issue-huge-icons-rendering-kml-files). It's not a bug but you can see the latest comment in the accepted answer, I could set to 1 or 1.0 the scale attribute so I was force to set it to 1.1 but today placemark icons are not displayed anymore.

This happens in several applications that they've been running for years without issues and we've changed nothing.

http://tripcaddy.es/mapa

http://mapadesevilla.geographica.gs

http://mirador.dipusevilla.es

Any ideas?

Thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

It looks like google has changed the default color tag for `<IconStyle>`. Now you must specify the color tag, if you don't specify the color tag it will be set to '00000000' and you won't see the icon because it's transparent.

Where could I find the tags that are mandatory and its default values for KMLs on google maps? I can't find it.

According to scale, today is now working with 1. We'll see what happen tomorrow...

I hope this help somebody.